# I have to run node as root to send icmp echo packages for ping - how can I make it secure?

Tags: linux, node.js, security

I'm using node's net-ping to enable my front end to ping by connecting to node via websockets. Because linux will only let root users send out ping requests I'm having to run the script via sudo. I'm not at all comfortable doing this but I don't think I have very much choice.

What I would like to know is are there any other ways to get permissions to send ping requests or if not, what steps should I take to make it secure as possible?

Dev server is Ubuntu Desktop 13.10x64 and production server is ubuntu server 12.04x64

EDIT:

I have node running a script that sets up a sockets.io socket server and listens for requests from the front end (website) to do a ping on a host. It then runs the ping via net-ping and sends the results back to the client as they come in. In this way I can run almost realtime pings via the website. The websockets themselves don't run the pings, they just let the "ping server" and the client communicate.

Comment: There should be dedicated capability for this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.general/42905

Comment: Websockets usually operate on port 80, and are handled by your webserver on the server side; `net-ping` on the other hand sends actual ICMP ECHO packets to your server that are handled by the OS itself. It's not clear how exactly you're using `net-ping` to ping via websockets, as it doesn't make much sense. If you describe your scenario in more detail, it might turn out that you don't actually need to ping over ICMP, so you might be able to avoid running as root in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access to ports < 1024 is protected on Linux. And I agree: Running node.js as root might not be a smart idea.

Try to execute the command `/bin/ping` instead. It's a SUID command which means it'll become root just to send the ping.

An alternate solution would be to run 2 node.js processes. One takes commands from the web and the other sends the pings. The outer server becomes a kind of smart firewall for the protected ping server which runs as root and only accepts connections from `localhost`.

Comment: Running the bare-bones `ping` binary is probably wiser than trusting a much more complex `node` environment with root privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I have swapped over to spawning /bin/ping as a child process and it works without root. It's also much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own ping implementation with the [raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) module. [Hear](https://github.com/davidgatti/Deconstructing-Ping-with-C-and-NodeJS) is a nice article explaining how to do it.

It might be an over kill but on the other hand you'll gain full control on how to execute the ping, and how to handle everything.

I hope it this helps.